# SQLite Read error in onReceive

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I'm building a test application to block incoming calls to a phone based off a database list. The database runs fine, the problem I'm running into is with the call receiver. When I try to read the database and check the incoming call against the values in the database I get an error.

Code I am using:

```
package com.call.blocker;

import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.util.Log;
import com.android.internal.telephony.ITelephony;

public class CustomBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private static final String TAG = "Phone Call";
    Context context = null;
    private ITelephony telephonyService;

    public String[] GatherNumbers() {
        int i = 0;
        Dbhelper dbHelper = new Dbhelper(CustomBroadcastReceiver.this);
        SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase(); //Problem is here

        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT " + Dbhelper.C_NUM + " FROM " + Dbhelper.TABLE, null);
        String[] myNumbers = new String[cursor.getCount() - 1];
        if (cursor != null) {
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    myNumbers[i] = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Dbhelper.C_NUM));
                    i++;
                } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }
        }
        return myNumbers;
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        TelephonyManager telephony = (TelephonyManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

        if (null == bundle)
            return;

        Log.v(TAG, bundle.toString() + "  1");

        String state = bundle.getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);

        Log.v(TAG, "State: " + state + "  2");

        if (state.equalsIgnoreCase(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {
            String phonenumber = bundle
                    .getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
            Log.v(TAG, "Incomng Number: " + phonenumber);

            try {
                String[] MyNumbers = GatherNumbers();
                Class c = Class.forName(telephony.getClass().getName());
                Method m = c.getDeclaredMethod("getITelephony");
                m.setAccessible(true);
                telephonyService = (ITelephony) m.invoke(telephony);
                telephonyService.silenceRinger();
                telephonyService.endCall();
                Log.v(TAG, "Ending Call");

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.v(TAG, "Error Ending Call");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Which is giving me this in the LogCat:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:118)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:187)
at com.call.blocker.CustomBroadcastReceiver.GatherNumbers(CustomBroadcastReceiver.java:22)
at com.call.blocker.CustomBroadcastReceiver.onReceive(CustomBroadcastReceiver.java:59)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:1769)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2400(ActivityThread.java:117)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:978)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3647)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I cant seem to figure out why it's having trouble opening the database and crashing the app. If I remove the line

```
String[] MyNumbers = GatherNumbers();
```

it has no problems blocking all calls. But with that line in the try fails.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it be

```
Dbhelper dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
```

?

BTW context field is always null, it seems.

Comment: Still gives me the same problems. And even with the context staying null it doesnt seem to affect the part of the script thats giving me problems